# Using a ForEach loop to count occurrences of a security logfile ID in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm currently attempting to count certain occurrences in logfiles using a For Each loop in Powershell. I've attempted many different versions of the same script but this is what I have at the moment:

```
$id = 4624

$instanceids = (get-eventlog security).instanceid

foreach ( $id in $instanceids ) {
$count ++
Write-Host " The amount of 4624's in the security log is $count"
}
```

My issue is, the loop counts how many security log files there are, not the logfiles with Id's named 4624. I'm not permitted to use Measure-Object or .count in this unfortunatley.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count the occurrence of a specific InstanceId:

```
$id = 4624

$InstanceIds = Get-EventLog -Logname Security -InstanceId $id
$Count       = ( $InstanceIds | Measure-Object ).Count

Write-Host "The amount of 4624's in the security log is $count"
```

Notice you can use the `-InstanceId` parameter to filter more efficiently.  Then use `Measure-Object` to get the count rather than looping it yourself.

To demonstrate what was wrong with your loop, you weren't counting conditionally. And, you were Writing output for every loop iteration.  This would have worked:

```
$id = 4624
$instanceids = (get-eventlog security).InstanceId

foreach ( $Instanceid in $instanceids ) {
If( $_.InstanceId -eq $id){ $count++ }
}

Write-Host " The amount of 4624's in the security log is $count"
```

Note: For performance reasons it's better to move filtering to the left. So, when there is a native capability in the cmdlet you should try and use it.  That said, if you are going to use a loop it can still be more efficient than the previous sample.

```
$id = 4624

Get-EventLog security -InstanceId $id |
ForEach-Object{ $count ++ }

Write-Host " The amount of 4624's in the security log is $count"
```

I'd also point out [Get-WinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.1) is newer and far more capable for this sort of thing.  Get-EventLog has been removed from PowerShell 7...